# Regular expression for numbers with decimal

Tags: javascript, regex

In my phonegap app I need to validate the textbox with regular expression which should contain only numbers and two decimal places.

Here is sample I have tried:

```
rexp: /^-?\d+\.?\d*$/
```

This code allows only numbers but after the dot(.) its accepting many numbers. But I should allow only two. Please guide me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 2):

You can make the number of matches explicit using the "{x}" modifier:

```
rexp: /^-?\d+\.?(\d{2})?$/
```

I suspect that you want to only have the two digits when there is a dot specified. Then you would modify you regexp as follows:

```
rexp: /^-?\d+(\.\d{2})?$/
```

I have created a JSFiddle to show the workings of the regexes and the difference between them: http://jsfiddle.net/q8NAz/

Comment: @FabrícioMatté Correct, I haved fixed this.

Comment: @Erik i have used your both the code and now i cannot able to type anything in textbox

Comment: @Sudha I have added a JSFiddle that shows how they work

Comment: I have fixed this using ^-?\d+\.?\d?\d?$

Comment: @Sudha I don't believe that is correct. That version will also successfully match the strings '77.' and '77.1' (see http://jsfiddle.net/q8NAz/1/). I do believe the correct answer is '/^-?\d+(\.\d{2})?$/'